# Changed to V4 masterpage not reverted previous style

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a publishing site and copied the v4 masterpage then changed the style to hide the quicklaunch bar in v4 copy masterpage.

When I reverted the masterpage to v4 masterpage, the page is not rendered with quick launch bar. I did check in developer tools and found the css used to hide quick launch, though I did not modify any thing in v4 masterpage.

Even I created a new publishing site with v4 master, I am still not able to render quick launch there.

Please point me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, I hope I understood you correctly:

1) You changed Masterpage style to hide the quick launch bar

2) You changed it back to render the quick launch bar, but it is not rendered correctly ("old" behaviour).

I came to a slightly similar problem here. My Problem was, that I had to "approve" every change I made on the masterpage. Via UI it's in your SiteCollection (~site) and then something like this. `/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

Then you see the library containing your changed masterpage. By clicking on the masterpage, you can approve it via ribbon menu item "approve/decline" or something liek that (using german version here).

As far as I remember there is a status for the masterpage shown in the list too, which shouldn't say "approved" but "due" or something like that (sorry, using german version here, in german it's "ausstehend", might be a little different than my translations here).

I hope this helps to solve your problem.

Best regards,
Dominik

Comment: I've run into that one myself, sounds like the right fix for this situation.

Comment: In English, "ausstehend" ("outstanding", literally) is displayed as "Pending". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spmoderationstatustype.aspx Ich liebe Deutsch.

Comment: Actually I created the copy of v4 master page and did changes in the copied master page. I approved the copied v4 master page and quick launch hiding worked fine. My problem was, when I create another new site with v4 master page, the quick launch was not rendered. When I see developer tools, it is showing quick launch hide css though I did not use that css any where in v4 master. I didn't modify v4 master page at all.